# How can I cast Vector<Complex> to Vector<Double>?

Tags: c#, math.net

I am working in C# with the Math.Net Numerics library and mainly using `Vector<T>` and `Matrix<T>` objects (doing linear regressions, finding eigenvalues, etc...). Mostly I'm working with complex numbers so I'm using `Vector<Complex>` (or matrix equivalent), but I also need to use `Vector<Double>` sometimes. My question is, therefore, how can I cast a `Vector<Complex>` to a `Vector<Double>`? Alternately, is there a way to get/set only the real (or imaginary) part of the whole Vector? I am doing this in C# which is a language I'm relatively new to (mostly I use C/C++ and MATLAB) so I apologize if this seems like a simple question.

Possible Examples:

```
Vector<Double> someDoubleVector; // already exists
Vector<Complex> someComplexVector; // ditto
double[] doubleArray; // ditto
double[] anotherDoubleArray; // ditto
someDoubleVector = someComplexVector.GetReal();
```

or

```
someDoubleVector = (Vector<Double>)someComplexVector;
```

or (setting just the real)

```
someComplexVector.SetReal(someDoubleVector);
```

or

```
someComplexVector.SetReal(doubleArray);
```

or when creating

```
Vector<Complex> anotherComplexVector = Vector<Complex>.Build.Dense(Vector<Double> realValues, Vector<Double> imagValues);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Map` method to convert between the types. If you need this often, you could define the following extension methods:

```
static class VectorExtensions
{
    public static Vector<double> Real(this Vector<Complex> v)
    {
        return v.Map(x => x.Real);
    }
    public static Vector<double> Imag(this Vector<Complex> v)
    {
        return v.Map(x => x.Imaginary);
    }
}
```

And then simply call

```
var someDoubleVector = someComplexVector.Real();
```

The same approach would also work for other similar conversions.

**Update 2015-12-30:** this functionality has been integrated into Math.NET Numerics since v3.10.

Comment: NB, this is common enough that we should consider to add such extension methods to Math.NET Numerics directly.

Comment: Perfect! This does exactly what I want. Thank you.